# Is there a way to Audit or Protect my data from relationships that don't fit my business?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have several relationships (and more are found weekly) that I don't want in my database.

For example:

> Column A in table Widget can't be null if this other value in this other table is set to true...

Short of coding my own system to audit my database and output a report, is there any good way to deal with this?

I have to think that I am not the first one to have business constraints that can't easily be codified into SQL Server...

**NOTE:** I am not looking for an enforcement system. Just a system to let me know when the rules have been broken.

Comment: Most DB Devs try to avoid 'codifying' business constraints into databases.  But you can build custom functions that are used in constraints in your table definitions.  Come up with a more specific request and someone can probably help you.

Comment: Or if you really want business rules in your DB, you can implement them with triggers also.  But I agree with tommy_o that the DB is not the place for those kinds of rules.

Comment: You seem to be saying that you have some business rules, and you want to find data in the database that breaks those rules. If so, then the obvious solution is to define the rules clearly and then write queries to find the invalid data. But I'm not sure that's really the answer you're looking for? Can you be more specific about what you're asking for? Are you trying to use a specific language or tool rather than plain TSQL, for example?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a limited amount of these business rules and that the rules are fairly simple like the one you described below.

In this case I’d just create one stored procedure per business rule that would report all rows that brake this rule. Then I’d run all of these scheduled at some time daily or weekly or give me the data I need.

Now, if you really have a lot of these then this approach might not be the best because it would allow a lot of maintenance and perhaps perf issues with running a ton of stored procedures at once.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't code business logic into the db, but if you insist, you can look into [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), this way on inser/update you can do a check or validation and then allow insert, rollback, or do X

**Update:**

Depending on when and how often you need to be informed of when the rules have been broken, you can do one of several things, off the top of my head here are three simple ways to achieve what you need

1. Have an application that runs outside of the db and on a scheduled
   basis to analyze and report the breach
2. Create a job with SQL Server Agent to run the checks for you and alert you
3. Have a trigger that alerts you every time a breach happens

With option #1 everything can be done outside of db and imho is simplest, with #2 and #3 if you need to just log or insert some data into some tracking table can be simple, if you want a full blown "alert" system like e-mail etc, you will probably need to involve [SQL CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you wish to do something fancy, or for just e-mail then you can do also try [SQL Mail](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

Comment: I should probably clarify.  I am not looking for an enforcement system.  Just a system to let me know when the rules have been broken.

Comment: @Vaccano see my updated answer, hope it gives you what you need to get started in the right direction